# In the delayed choice quantum eraser, how does Alice verify the equation $\langle\sigma_1\rangle_n=n\cdot x$?

Tags: entanglement

I'm reading chapter 2 of Preskill's notes on quantum information. In explaining the delayed choice, he says that out of the two observers Alice and Bob,

Alice could measure all of her spins today (say along **x**) before Bob has made his mind up how he will measure his spins. Next week, Bob can decide
to “prepare” Alice’s spins in the states **$\left| n+ \right>_A$** and **$\left| n- \right>_A$** (that is the “delayed choice”). He then tells Alice which were the **$\left| n+ \right>_A$** spins, and she can check her measurement record to verify that
**$\langleσ_1\rangle_n = n.x$**

I did not understand since Alice measured her spins along x axis, how did she verify the equation **$\langleσ_1\rangle_n = n.x$** since she did not measure along n-axis. I mean, how that fact that Bob made a delayed choice is being used here? It would be helpful if someone provides a detailed explanation of this.

EDIT: Link to lecture notes: [http://theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/ph219/index.html#lecture](http://theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph219/index.html#lecture)
See chapter 2, section 2.5.4, pg 70

Comment: Hi @AninditaSarkar, please share a link to these lecture notes.

Comment: Please add the lecture notes to the post

Comment: @YaronJarach done, check the post now

Comment: @MarkSpinelli yeah edited accordingly.